# git diff shows wrong diffs

Tags: git, rsync, git-diff

I am reviewing some changes on a repo with git.
On several files, `git diff` shows the full file as changed.
However, no changes were made.
Here is the output:

```
$ git diff classes/cache/index.php                                                                         
diff --git a/classes/cache/index.php b/classes/cache/index.php                                                                                                     
index a7d0f33f6..a0a30515d 100644                                                                                                                                  
--- a/classes/cache/index.php                                                                                                                                      
+++ b/classes/cache/index.php                                                                                                                                      
@@ -1,35 +1,35 @@                                                                                                                                                  
-<?php                                                                                                                                                             
-/*                                                                                                                                                                
-* 2007-2016 PrestaShop                                                                                                                                            
-*                                                                                                                                                                 
-* NOTICE OF LICENSE                                                                                                                                               
-*                                                                                                                                                                 
-* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)                                                                                              
-* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.                                                                                                      
-* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:                                                                                                    
-* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php                                                                                                                      
-* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to                                                                                                  
-* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email                                                                                                      
-* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.                                                                                                
+<?php                                                                                                                                                             
+/*                                                                                                                                                                
+* 2007-2016 PrestaShop                                                                                                                                            
+*                                                                                                                                                                 
+* NOTICE OF LICENSE
+*
+* This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
+* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
+* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
+* http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
+* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
+* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
+* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
```

`git diff` shows the whole file prefixed with `-`, then again the same text with `+`.
What could disturb `git diff`?
Note that this repo was previously synced with `rsync` (however the permissions were preserved).

Comment: Line ending between Windows & Linux?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-diff%5D+whole+file